# Losing elements of nested list while displaying them for a second time

Tags: c, linked-list, nested-lists

I am trying to bulid a "library" using nested lists. Everything worked fine, I could add elements using my sorted add functions until I noticed, that if I display the list two times in a row, for the first time everything will be fine, but in the second one "book elements" added to catalogs are not displayed, like they are not there.

```
struct book
{
    char *title;
    int number;
    char *country;
    struct book* new;
};

struct catalog
{
    char *name;
    struct catalog* next;
    struct book* firstbook;
};

void printList(struct catalog *head)
{
    struct catalog *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->firstbook == NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", temp->name);

        }
        while(temp->firstbook != NULL)
        {   printf("%s  ", temp->name);
            printf("%s  ", temp->firstbook->title);
            printf("%d  ", temp->firstbook->number);
            printf("%s\n", temp->firstbook->country);
            temp->firstbook = temp->firstbook->new;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

struct book *newbook(char *booktitle, int number, char *country)
{
    struct book* newbook = (struct book*) malloc(sizeof(struct book));
    newbook->title = malloc(sizeof(strlen(booktitle)+1));
    newbook->country = malloc(sizeof(strlen(country)+1));
    newbook->title = booktitle;
    newbook->country = country;
    newbook->number = number;
    newbook->new = NULL;
}

struct catalog *findcatalog(struct catalog** head, char *catalogname)
{
    struct catalog* current;
    current = *head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->name == catalogname)
        {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void sortedBookInsert(struct catalog** head, char *catalogname, char *booktitle, int number, char *country)
{
    struct catalog* searched;
    struct book* pom;
    struct book* ksiazka = newbook(booktitle, number, country);
    searched = findcatalog(head, catalogname);
    if(searched->firstbook == NULL || strcmp(searched->firstbook->title, ksiazka->title)>0)
    {
        ksiazka->new =searched->firstbook;
        searched->firstbook = ksiazka;
    }
    else
    { pom = searched->firstbook;
        while(pom->new!= NULL && strcmp(searched->firstbook->title, ksiazka->title)< 0)
        {
            pom = pom->new;
        }
        ksiazka->new = pom->new;
        pom->new = ksiazka;
    }
}

void sortedInsert(struct catalog** head,char *name)
{
    struct catalog* current;
    struct catalog* new_node = newcatalog(name);

    if (*head == NULL || strcmp((*head)->name, new_node->name) > 0)
    {
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        current = *head;
        while (current->next!=NULL && strcmp(current->next->name, new_node->name) < 0)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

int main()
{

```
struct catalog* head = NULL;
sortedInsert(&head, "Kappa");
sortedInsert(&head, "Aaaaaa");
sortedInsert(&head, "Sdafscx");
sortedInsert(&head, "Saxzxc");
sortedInsert(&head, "Asdas");
sortedInsert(&head, "Zzzzzzzz");
sortedInsert(&head, "Country");
sortedBookInsert(&head, "Country", "PKP", 11111, "Germany");
sortedBookInsert(&head, "Country", "Polacy", 11112, "Italy");
sortedBookInsert(&head, "Country", "Autobusy", 11234, "France");
sortedBookInsert(&head, "Country", "Polityka", 14111, "Russia");
printList(head);
printList(head);
return 0;
```

}

```
When I print my list for a second time, elements from SortedBookInsert just... are not there. I am very confused.
```

Comment: you have mainly missing returns, look at my answer allowing to have a (a priori) valid version / execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a return is missing in *newbook*, must be

```
struct book *newbook(char *booktitle, int number, char *country)
{
    struct book* newbook = (struct book*) malloc(sizeof(struct book));
    newbook->title = malloc(sizeof(strlen(booktitle)+1));
    newbook->country = malloc(sizeof(strlen(country)+1));
    newbook->title = booktitle;
    newbook->country = country;
    newbook->number = number;
    newbook->new = NULL;

    return newbook;
}
```

without the return the behavior is undefined.

Note also you create 2 memory leaks doing :

> ```
> newbook->title = malloc(sizeof(strlen(booktitle)+1));
> newbook->country = malloc(sizeof(strlen(country)+1));
> newbook->title = booktitle;
> newbook->country = country;
> ```

but also you do not allocate the right length because of the *sizeof*, must be

```
newbook->title = malloc(strlen(booktitle)+1);
newbook->country = malloc(strlen(country)+1);
strcpy(newbook->title, booktitle);
strcpy(newbook->country, country);
```

In *findcatalog* there is no return too in case the catalog is not found, must be

```
struct catalog *findcatalog(struct catalog** head, char *catalogname)
{
    struct catalog* current;
    current = *head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->name == catalogname)
        {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

without the return the behavior is undefined.

In *sortedBookInsert* may be you need to check if *searched* is not NULL before to do `searched->firstbook`, for instance :

```
void sortedBookInsert(struct catalog** head, char *catalogname, char *booktitle, int number, char *country)
{
    struct catalog* searched;
    struct book* pom;
    struct book* ksiazka = newbook(booktitle, number, country);
    searched = findcatalog(head, catalogname);
    if (searched == NULL)
      return;
    if(searched->firstbook == NULL || strcmp(searched->firstbook->title, ksiazka->title)>0)
    {
        ksiazka->new =searched->firstbook;
        searched->firstbook = ksiazka;
    }
    else
    { pom = searched->firstbook;
        while(pom->new!= NULL && strcmp(searched->firstbook->title, ksiazka->title)< 0)
        {
            pom = pom->new;
        }
        ksiazka->new = pom->new;
        pom->new = ksiazka;
    }
}
```

but to be frank I am not sure of that

In *findcatalog*

> ```
> if(current->name == catalogname)
> ```

must be

```
if(!strcmp(current->name, catalogname))
```

The function *printList* modify the catalog doing `temp->firstbook = temp->firstbook->new;`, you need to replace

> ```
>    while(temp->firstbook != NULL)
>    {   printf("%s  ", temp->name);
>        printf("%s  ", temp->firstbook->title);
>        printf("%d  ", temp->firstbook->number);
>        printf("%s\n", temp->firstbook->country);
>        temp->firstbook = temp->firstbook->new;
>    }
> ```

by for instance :

```
struct book* firstbook = temp->firstbook;

    while(firstbook != NULL)
    {   printf("%s  ", temp->name);
        printf("%s  ", firstbook->title);
        printf("%d  ", firstbook->number);
        printf("%s\n", firstbook->country);
        firstbook = firstbook->new;
    }
```

If I do all these modifications and use this definition :

```
struct catalog* newcatalog(char *name)
{
  struct catalog* r = malloc(sizeof(struct catalog));

  r->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
  strcpy(r->name, name);
  r->next = NULL;
  r->firstbook = NULL;

  return r;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
one
Aaaaaa
Asdas
Country  Autobusy  11234  France
Country  PKP  11111  Germany
Country  Polacy  11112  Italy
Country  Polityka  14111  Russia
Kappa
Saxzxc
Sdafscx
Zzzzzzzz
two
Aaaaaa
Asdas
Country  Autobusy  11234  France
Country  PKP  11111  Germany
Country  Polacy  11112  Italy
Country  Polityka  14111  Russia
Kappa
Saxzxc
Sdafscx
Zzzzzzzz
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==7575== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7575== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7575== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7575== Command: ./a.out
==7575== 
one
Aaaaaa
Asdas
Country  Autobusy  11234  France
Country  PKP  11111  Germany
Country  Polacy  11112  Italy
Country  Polityka  14111  Russia
Kappa
Saxzxc
Sdafscx
Zzzzzzzz
two
Aaaaaa
Asdas
Country  Autobusy  11234  France
Country  PKP  11111  Germany
Country  Polacy  11112  Italy
Country  Polityka  14111  Russia
Kappa
Saxzxc
Sdafscx
Zzzzzzzz
==7575== 
==7575== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7575==     in use at exit: 148 bytes in 11 blocks
==7575==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 1 frees, 1,172 bytes allocated
==7575== 
==7575== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7575==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==7575==    indirectly lost: 136 bytes in 10 blocks
==7575==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7575==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7575==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7575== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==7575== 
==7575== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7575== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from
```

---

Note in your code you give literal strings for the names/booktitles/countries so they never disappear/change so to duplicate them is useless, but this will not be the case in a 'real' case where you reuse the same array or character getting them from file or reading them on stdin etc, so I recommend you to duplicate them as I proposed

Comment: This leads to the conclusion that warnings were not turned on, otherwise the compiler would have complained.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie absolutely, or the OP didn't take them into account

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not use Valgrind(in fact, I have never used it, I am just starting with programming) and my compiler did not give me any warnings. What my main question was/is however, is why are book elements not printed in the second print of linked list and how to fix it, so they are printed. I thought they are properly inserted to a certain catalog, but they just disapperar and I don't know why. Could you help me with that problem?

Comment: @Tytanuser I didn't see before an error because of unexpected _sizeof_, I edited my answer please reread it, now the executions are two times the same. I didn't see these error using valgrind because I replaced the malloc/strcpy by the use of _strdup_ when I did tests

Comment: @bruno So it seems like now there is a bigger problem in my _sortedBookInsert_ function, because now it doesn't add books to catalogs at all, but I don't know why, it worked previously

Comment: @Tytanuser I see an other error in _findcatalog_ `if(current->name == catalogname)` must be `if(!strcmp(current->name, catalogname))` but doing that the 2 executions are not the same

Comment: @bruno Maybe it will be easier if I add elements without sorting them and then sort them using another function?

Comment: @Tytanuser I found, _printList_ modified your catalog, I edited my answer reread it. However it is not clear it is needed to duplicates the name/title/country. Also to check `if (searched == NULL)` in _sortedBookInser_ seems not mandatory

Comment: @Tytanuser do you need I put all the code in my answer ?

Comment: @bruno Thank you very much for your help, it works as I was supposed to now!

Comment: @bruno No, I understood and modified my code accordingly to what you wrote, thank you!

Comment: @bruno Sorry, just did it

Comment: @Tytanuser no problem, happy coding